# scala : getwords similar to getlines

Tags: scala, file-io

I want to write a piece of code that looks like following :

```
var wordItr = Source.fromFile("myfile").getWords
while (wordItr.hasNext) {
  val word = wordItr.next
  process(word)
}
```

Reason behind this logic is "myfile" file is really big (around 10GB) and has no line breaks and writing a code like above really helps.

Can you please suggest how to code `wordItr`

Answer (score 3):

```
 Source.fromFile("myfile").getLines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
```

or

```
import java.io.File
import java.util.Scanner
var wordItr = new Scanner(new File("myFile")).useDelimiter(" ")
```

Comment: I tried this. It won;t work for files with no linebreaks ("\n") and whose file is approx 10GB.

Comment: maybe you want something like a java Scanner?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html.  You can set the deliminter to the " " and pull in one word at a time so you don't pull 10 gigs into memory at one.